# How to install Opera Browser?

Tags: command-line, software-center, google-chrome, browser, opera

I am trying to install opera browser from the terminal.  I downloaded the 'debian' installer because it didn't show up in software center.

It completely destroyed my software center - it is frozen and I have no idea how to fix (I have a different thread for that though).

Can I use this thing called synaptic package manager to install Opera?  or am I stuck with Firefox?

How do I install Opera Browser?

Comment: You have asked a lot of questions here.  In future can you limit your questions to one topic for each question.  It makes it easier for us to answer (and more questions means more chances to earn reputation. Also questions are easier to read if you use correct capitalisation and puctuation.

Comment: To pick up on some of the questions Opera is being dealt with as answers but [Ubuntu Commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal), [sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), [synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto).  If you these sites do not cover what you need to know ask a separate question about each.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Synaptic is a graphical interface for Aptitude, the package manager in Ubuntu/Linux. It provides a listing of available software packages that are available to download and install from the repositories listed in your Software Sources. Synaptic is less intimidating to use than `apt-get` in a Terminal interface for users not used to dealing with the command line.

Preceding commands in Terminal/command line with `sudo` imparts a restricted root-user ability for performing commands that are not available for standard user accounts.

When in doubt about any basic command in Terminal, you can always `man [base command]` to access the command manual pages. `man sudo` will show the manual for `sudo`, for example. There is also extensive documentation on the Ubuntu website for most commands.

As for installing Opera, it is not maintained in the standard Ubuntu repositories. You have two options:

1) add the Opera repository to your Software Sources as mentioned in the other answer and following the directions in the provided link; or

2) download and install Opera manually.

To install Opera manually, go to the Opera website (www.opera.com) and download it from there. Presuming that you have your downloads set to go to your Downloads Folder, you can run the following in Terminal:

`cd /home/your_account/Downloads ;ls -l`
Replace "your_account"  with your short name; the "ls -l" will list the contents of the Downloads folder. Locate the Opera package file - it should be something like 'Opera_12.15.1748_amd64.deb'.

`sudo dpkg -i Opera_12.15.1748_amd64.deb` and enter your password when prompted. This will run the Opera installer.

In order to have Opera updated automatically, you should still add the Opera repository to your list of software sources.

Comment: Thanks douggro.  I downloaded it and double clicked on it like it was an .msi yesterday.. It blew up software  center, update mgr, and synaptic.  I will try your method.

Answer (score 24):

**How to install Opera on Ubuntu:**

From the terminal, add a pointer to the opera stable sources:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list'
```

Install the key:

```
sudo sh -c 'wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -'
```

Update repo:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Opera:

```
sudo apt-get install opera
```

Comment: This works in ubuntu 14.04.01 / 14.10 as well.

Comment: no need to do this anymore, the deb you download from opera.com prompts you to install an apt source for you.

Comment: Works also on Ubuntu 16.04, but _"apt-get install opera"_ installs old version _12.x_. To install a current version use _"apt-get install opera-stable"_.

Comment: Use https://www.opera.com/computer/linux for latest version

Answer (score 7):

Opera is available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install Opera open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install opera
```

Opera web browser comes with built-in ad blocker, battery saver and free VPN.

Answer (score 5):

By the time this question was answered, things have evolved.

By now, you can simply go to [Download Opera browser](http://www.opera.com/download), then click the button above **Opera for Windows, Mac or Linux** and the website will detect your operating system and processor architecture (32 or 64 bits) using [device fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) and prompt you a [`.deb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) package to download and install by a simple click using the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/).

**Update (09/12/2017):**

I just tested this again on 2 different virtual machines (Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04 LTS), and the procedure worked as described above.

Comment: This is true, though after it downloaded the package (in both FF and Chrome) the installer would do nothing after I clicked the **Install** button. The command line instructions for `dpkg` in [douggro](https://askubuntu.com/users/150221/douggro)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/291026/763159) proved successful in installing it.

Comment: Does not work for me in Ubuntu 16.04. The installer downloads, and runs, with a brief panel offering an "Install" button. Clicking the button does nothing, even after waiting several minutes.

Comment: I just re-tested that on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM and it works as described. I can not figure out what is your issue, it is better to ask a new question and take screenshots of what you got.@BasilBourque

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).

Import the public signing key for Opera

```
wget -qO- https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Run the following command to add Opera browser repository to the system.

```
echo "deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list
```

Update the repository index.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the Opera browser using the apt command.

```
sudo apt-get install -y opera-stable
```

While installing Opera, the installer will ask you to set up Opera repository for easy upgrade of Opera browser by which you can easily upgrade Opera during the regular system upgrades. Choose Yes and press enter.

Access Opera Browser as follows:
Go to Activities >> Search for Opera.