# Installing Opera browser on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I've just download Opera .deb package and I can't install it. When I type sudo dpkg -i, terminal is showing errors:

```
sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_40.0.2308.62_i386.deb
dpkg: regarding opera-stable_40.0.2308.62_i386.deb containing opera-stable:i386, pre-dependency problem:
 opera-stable:i386 pre-depends on apt-transport-https
  apt-transport-https is not installed.  


dpkg: error processing archive opera-stable_40.0.2308.62_i386.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing opera-stable:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 opera-stable_40.0.2308.62_i386.deb
```

by the way, I use Ubuntu 16.04 x64 and downloaded opera i386 (x32). does it make sense?

thanks, I've managed to install it, I downloaded x64 version. But now I can't reach any site:

"This site can’t be reached

The connection was reset.

Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Check your internet connection.
Check any cables and reboot any routers, modems, or other network devices you may be using.

Allow Opera to access the network in your firewall or antivirus settings.
If it is already listed as a program allowed to access the network, try removing it from the list and adding it again.

If you use a proxy server...
Check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server: Go to the Main menu > Settings > Change proxy settings... > LAN Settings and deselect "Use a proxy server for your LAN".

But I'm surfing the net on firefox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Opera Browser?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291001/how-to-install-opera-browser)

Comment: no, installing opera for i386 on a 64bit install does not make much sense

Answer (score 1):

> opera-stable:i386 pre-depends on apt-transport-https
>   apt-transport-https is not installed.

As you see you just need to install `apt-transport-https`

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https
dpkg -i opera-stable_*.deb
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can Install *gdebi* :

> sudo apt-get install gdebi

Now you can install install any *.deb* package. It will download all dependencies.

> sudo gdebi opera-stable_40.0.2308.62_i386.deb

Comment: gdebi is a good idea, but OP is trying to install a i386 package on a x64 machine, probably a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

After your `dpkg -i` command, run `sudo apt-get -f install` to install any further dependency. It should fetch required dependency packages.

You must have main repository enabled for this. To do so, use this command

```
sudo apt-add-repository main
```

Then update the package index with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then again try using `sudo apt-get -f install`

After your last edit, it seems you download Opera 32bit for 64bit. It doesn't make sense unless you really need 32bit for some reason. Download 64 bit.

Alternatively, you can try using 32bit. In that case, use these command

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

then use `sudo apt-get -f install` to complete installation.

Comment: I did:           0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 112 not upgraded.

Comment: Do you have all repository enabled? Check in "Software & Updates".

Comment: There are only 2 repositories:

Canoncial partners

Comment: @Steve there should have more repositories enabled. See my edit

Comment: 'main' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.

Comment: @Steve is your problem solved?