# Opera - your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available

Tags: video, youtube, opera, html5

I'm using opera browser version 56.0.3051.43 on Ubuntu 16.04 with I3wm and I get

> your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available

when trying to play some videos on youtube on respect to **HTML5**. I've seen a couple forums about this, but only about very outdated versions and none are very clear steps. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does the html5 page of youtube say? https://www.youtube.com/html5  Maybe Opera just doesn't support many formats... period.

Comment: @Xen2050 it says opera supports HTML5 videos.

Comment: There's six different "checkbox" formats on the page for me, plus a 7th for "The HTML5 player is currently used when possible." Do you only see one "checkbox," and which one?

Comment: I have a ! mark in `H.246` and in `MSE & H.264`, but the HTML checkbox is alright.

Comment: For me Chromium has checkmarks in those two H.264 ones, but red `!`'s for the right two with WebM, Youtube has never complained... Are opera and all the video-related packages updated? There might be an extension/add-on to try asking for different video formats, chromium has some to request H.264, and block 60FPS videos (otherwise it's forced for higher res sometimes, terrible!) but I'm not sure about Opera. Web search found some ideas, I'd might as well post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had installed opera with the `deb` package downloadable from [Opera's site](https://www.opera.com/download) and it did not load HTML 5 videos from youtube. The only solution that worked for me was to uninstall the version I had with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge opera-stable
```

and then installed the version from the PPA package following this other AskUbuntu [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/475542/670805).

Adding a pointer to the opera stable sources:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list'
```

Install the key:

```
sudo sh -c 'wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -'
```

Fetch the new repository:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install latest Opera with:

```
sudo apt-get install opera-stable
```

Now Opera is able to handle HTML5 videos.

Comment: This time Opera had a problem [only with Ubuntu](https://forums.opera.com/post/166378) packages chromium-codecs-ffmpeg* so [linking Chromium codecs](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148025/266179) worked fine.

Answer (score 12):

Due to legal restrictions Opera is [unable to distribute H264 codec](https://forums.opera.com/topic/27375/opera-54-0-2952-41-streaming-videos-don-t-work-anymore/37). You can use the following workaround:

Install `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` package and create a link to `libffmpeg.so`:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so
```

You can check your opera installation directory in the About dialog.

Comment: This worked for me with Opera 60

Comment: It did not work for me,may i ask how to reverse it ?

Comment: @obo Just reinstall opera: `sudo apt-get install opera --reinstall`

Answer (score 2):

From a web search for [opera linux enable h.264](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=opera+linux+enable+h.264&t=h_&ia=web) I found this answer over on the Unix & Linux SE [H.264 support for Opera and openSUSE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384015/h-264-support-for-opera-and-opensuse) that suggests trying a few different ideas, but it lead to a more promising looking [Opera forum](https://forums.opera.com/topic/27474/please-explain-to-this-rookie-how-to-install-codecs-to-make-videos-work/14) from 4 months ago that might/should work:

> burnout426 4 months ago
> @drpostman A little bit better directions.
>
> Start Opera, goto, https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases/ and download the 0.31.4-linux-x64.zip file. In Opera's download dialog, click the folder icon to show the file in the file manager. Right-click it and choose "Extract here". This will give you `libffmpeg.so`.
>
> Right-click in a blank spot in the file manager and choose "open as root" and type in your password. Then, right-click on `libffmpeg.so` and choose cut.
>
> Then, in the file manager, browser to "`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/`". Right-click in a blank spot and choose to create a new folder named `lib_extra`. Once the folder is created, go into it, right-click on a blank spot and choose paste. You should then see `libffmpeg.so` there. Then, restart Opera and goto https://youtube.com/html5 to see if h.264 support is enabled for example. Then, test out some videos. On youtube, you can right-click on a video and choose "stats for nerds" to see if it's using vp9 or h.264. Or, you can try these h.264 videos to make sure they work.
>
> You can then close the file manager.
>
> (Tested on Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon x64)

Others answers that might be worth trying (from the earlier question) include:

- Copy a `libffmpeg.so` file from https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases or http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/chromium-beta/ubuntu/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/
- Use the [snap version of opera](https://snapcraft.io/opera)

Comment: Unfortunately, I followed the steps above and it did not work, but I got the solution now, I'll post the answer to my case.

Comment: This didn't worked for me, but Sergey answer does (sudo ln -sf ...)

Comment: This solution works for me. I'm using Opera 73 deb on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Downloaded `libffmpeg.so` from https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases and moved it to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/`

Answer (score 2):

The instructions by Sergey Podobry did not work for me on Ubuntu 19.10. Further digging into the issue, it seems that `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` does not have the necessary codec anymore. This can be notices if you look at the package list of files [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra).

Instead, this is what I did:

- Download the codec from an earlier Ubuntu release, Like 18.04, from [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_79.0.3945.79-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb).
- Extract the package, and then extract `data.tar.xz` file.
- Within the extracted folder, navigation to data/usr/lib/chromium-browser. You will find the codec named `libffmpeg.so`.
- Move this file to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/lib_extra`.
- Restart Opera.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not so much with Opera and in all fairness the issue here is with `libffmpeg.so` which is in fact proprietary codec support. I have a little script that adds the support you need after an Opera update or install. Get the script [here](https://infrabyte.com/pub/opera_codec.sh). Once you have it, make it executable and run it as follows.

```
chmod 755 opera_codec.sh
./opera_codec.sh
```

Hope this helps you out as it has always worked for me. You can then go test your html5 support at https://html5test.com

Answer (score 0):

My FIX: I went to https://www.youtube.com/html5 (Thx Grandpa Dave!),

- Scrolled to the BOTTOM YOUTUBE LOGO on left
- and just to the RIGHT of the bottom-left logo "LANGUAGE" and
- CORRECTED my location/LANGUAGE.

Everything played fine after that. Pls share if this worked for you. It's a weird auto-location selection. I thought there might be a prob when the comp auto-filled my date/time with another country time, sure enough, youtube matched the incorrect auto location.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a one-line Opera install script you can use the following:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/icolwell/install_scripts/master/opera_install.bash | bash
```

I've updated the install script according to [Sergey Podobry's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148025/688415) so it will link the correct video codecs. The script is hosted [here](https://github.com/icolwell/install_scripts/blob/master/opera_install.bash).