# Can't watch Videos on Opera

Tags: codecs

I'm an ex Manjaro user, I installed Opera from the package manager and it gave me options to install other optional things. I didn't install chromium codecs first, and was unable to play any videos on Opera. I reinstalled it and selected those codecs and everything was fine. 
.
.
Now I have switched to Ubuntu 19.04 for stability reasons. 
Installed Opera and same issues with videos. I checked and saw latest chromium codecs were installed. 
What should I do now?

Comment: Check in software store and see if you have the snap opera or the deb.  Snap option seems to have trouble with permissions.

Comment: I downloaded the Opera Stable .deb from their official site

Comment: Is it a matter of all videos not playing or just certain ones.  I have opera also and after opera updates, facebook videos won't play till more opera updates happen, usually a week or two.  Opera does not have access for DRM videos.

Comment: Facebook videos and some youtube videos too. Well I posted here because it runs on Manjaro (on my laptop) So I thought there's probably some issues with codecs

Comment: I would give it a week or two and see if newer updates for opera  fix the problem.  Opera won't play drm videos like 'buffy or angel' on facebook watch but should play most of the uploaded videos from sites/people most of the time.  It is one of the few things opera is not good at.

Comment: you're probably right, the thing that's annoying me is that same version of Opera, on same machine plays facebook videos on Manjaro but won't play on Ubuntu. Also on windows it's fine.

Comment: Wonder if Manjaro has some codecs that ubuntu doesn't?  Do you have 'ubuntu restricted extras' installed?

Comment: I don't know what you meant by "ubuntu restricted extras", if it meant other os, then no, I had a clean install of Ubuntu 19.04,, erased everything on my HDD

Comment: restricted extras is found in software centre and is usually suggested to add during install of ubuntu.  Adds codecs and a few other things that ubuntu can't add by themselves during install.

Comment: Was just checking something else and found this, might be useful, going try it myself.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091183/opera-your-browser-does-not-currently-recognize-any-of-the-video-formats-avail

Comment: Found that the answer at bottom works for me, even the buffy type videos in facebook watch are working.