# Opera Browser script

Tags: scripts, opera

I'm trying to create a script that installs opera-stable silently.

Currently I am stuck at

[image]

How can I pre-select yes or no from my script?

I know this is possible to do with ms-corefonts with this command.

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true
```

Comment: If you're concerned with installing the latest stable version of Opera web browser, the [*opera* snap package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291001/how-to-install-opera-browser/291005#291005) ( `sudo snap install opera` ) is updated silently and automatically when updates are available.

Comment: @karel I appreciate the alternative. But currently I'm staying away from Snaps and Flatpak.