# How can I keep Opera installed on Ubuntu live USB?

Tags: live-usb

I have a problem my Hard Disk. So I am using a live USB of ubuntu. 
For using Opera browser, I am installing it each time I boot.
Is there a way to keep this installation after a system reboot with the live CD?

I want not to persiste all the installation of ubuntu on my USB. I want to know if it is just possible to persiste just one software (Opera) ?

Comment: Try installing the native Ubuntu Opera snap package: https://askubuntu.com/questions/291001/how-to-install-opera-browser/291005#291005 If you follow the instructions at [How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/) your Ubuntu live USB will have a storage space that is persistent across reboots.

Comment: You may want to try the [persistent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb) or full installation on the USB. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776#295776) for the difference.

Comment: Also see this [question about full install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator).

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You might find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1159251/225694) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To Make Opera persistent on a Live USB...

1. Follow the instructions in
   [How to make a persistent live Ubuntu USB with more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb)
   to create the **Persistent Live USB**.
2. Boot from this Live USB as you have done before.
3. Install Opera as you have done before.
4. Don't install anything else.

Now your Opera installation will remain in the Live USB.

Hope this helps

Comment: I followed the steps you proposed and it worked well
thank you

Comment: I am happy to help. Your up vote and the green check mark ✅ is sufficient. Stay on in this site, and may be you will be able to help someone else.