# How do I create Ubuntu Live CD with .config and .mozilla inside the ISO?

Tags: boot, live-usb, configuration

> My question was how to **insert in an existing live ISO** those two folders and not **"How to customize the "the whole" Ubuntu live CD?"** Having to install all the tools so that you can do it, and so forth. **Is this the only option from scratch?** No other way without installation of additional software **to insert** some **line of code** in some other **ISO config file**, telling it from where should be copied into the **/home/** folder?
>
> Or just simple **to execute some shell file** while ISO is still loading **to copy** straight **into the home folder**, those necessary folders.
>
> How can this be done? Without the suggested link? I do not wish to install anything, so that later I have to purge again.

---

> I need an **Ubuntu Live CD version with my own configuration files** on it.
>   Even an Ubuntu standard distro version is OK. ***Must not be mine personal.***

**When I boot** with a **live CD** and **copy that inside** the **/home/**, relogin **it works fine**, but I've to do this every time and that just drives me crazy. And sometimes I forget to bring with me those config files.

So I'm trying to insert **.config** and **.mozilla** inside **Ubuntu/Lubuntu Live CD**

(that is the config that I already have configured myself from OpenBox, panels, Mozilla plugins etc. and so on).

I've looked everywhere and just can't find the solution. I tried on my own, but no luck. In worse case scenario, it will not boot. I just don't know what to touch and what to do.

> I am **not interested to assign any additional space** for it **on Live USB** (from zero to xyz GB), as you can do that with **Pen Drive Linux** aka **Universal USB Installer** and others.

Why? Well from my experience:

1. Well because **it makes it too slow immediately**. USB flash even if USB
   3.0 is too slow for me. It drives me nuts like win10.
2. And because **I need it as a CD/DVD version too.**
3. I want to inject everything into a RAM (my 16 GB DDR4 works fine with it).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve your desired result by utilizing [SystemImageKit.](https://github.com/probonopd/SystemImageKit) The goal of this project is Image-based computing: Operating system complexity reduction by encapsulation. This is accomplished by utilizing the following features which appears (at least to me) to cover all of your requirements and more. This approach eliminates the need to customize the ISO completely.

- grub2 with custom helper scripts
- ISO files, containing one live operating system each
- ExtensionImage files, the contents of which are symlinked into the / upon boot
- AppImage files, the contents of which are mounted when the app is executed
- An init file that does local configuration and is run when the system boots (and an auxiliary initrd that helps loading this configuration)
- Files in $HOME which is mounted from a persistent location

Detailed information regarding this currently active project can be found in the projects [readme.md file.](https://github.com/probonopd/SystemImageKit/blob/master/README.md)