# How can I make a 19.04 persistent live USB from Windows?

Tags: live-usb, windows-10, 19.04, persistence

I am trying to make a persistent USB, but all the methods do not work. I haven't tried the mkusb method because I have Windows 10. So how would I make a persistent Ubuntu live USB from a Windows 10 computer?

Comment: Here is described: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: @pa4080 I said that I have windows 10 so I can not use mkusb, and the other method does not work anymore

Comment: Please keep reading the article and find the section "How to Make a Persistent Ubuntu USB Drive on Windows".

Comment: @pa4080 I saw that and it says it no longer works on the top of that section

Comment: In that case you can try to run live Ubuntu session from another media (CD or USB) and within that session you could install `mkusb` to create your persistent drive.

Comment: @pa4080 Could I do this with a VM or does it have to be another USB?

Comment: Great idea. I think, it should work. Depending on the virtual machine vendor there must have some settings to grant the virtual machine with direct access to the USB port(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679).  See the answer titled "Creating your own Custom Live CD - the manual way." - the method still works.  The .ISO would be static but you can customize the software and use extra space on USB for variable files.

Comment: @Nmath That's a kluge that should only be used as a last resort, not a duplicate question.

Comment: @Nmath Use *Related question:* or *Related:* instead of *Possible duplicate of* to point to useful related links that are not also duplicate links.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159004/how-do-i-create-ubuntu-live-cd-with-config-and-mozilla-inside-the-iso/1159251#1159251

Comment: I think this may be a bad ISO download problem, I have not had problem making a persistent install of 19.04 using Rufus, UNetbootin, Universal, YUMI, or YUMI UEFI.

Answer (score 5):

#### Ubuntu 19.10 and later

The best application for making a bootable Ubuntu live USB from Windows is [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). The official ubuntu.com website recommends using Rufus instead of UNetbootin. Step-by-step instructions for creating a bootable Ubuntu live USB from Windows are at [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Rufus persistent storage partition is supported in 19.10 and later. Please upgrade Rufus to version 3.9 or later.

[image: Rufus persistent storage]

#### Ubuntu 19.04 and earlier

[mkusb](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) is the most reliable tool for making an Ubuntu live USB with persistent file storage in 19.04 and earlier.

Comment: With this Live 4GB Persistent USB the op can install mkusb and use that to make a USB with unlimited persistence. or he can do a full install to another USB.

Comment: Is the space used to preserve the amount of space that the user can use without losing the data?

Comment: @TheRealTengri Yes, it is the amount of space that the user can use without losing the data.

Comment: Ok, I will test this tonight

Comment: It did not work for me: `operating systeme not found`