# Ubuntu On CD Installation

Tags: system-installation

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a CD that will allow boot-up if it is in the CD drive, but otherwise will allow Windows to boot?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Ubuntu does not fit on a CD anymore; assuming we are not talking about a mini ISO install. You need at least a DVD but those too are read only mediums so do not work that well: it will put everything into RAM making it slow.

You should use a USB stick if possible: you can make that "persistent" and have  more partitions on it so you can save files into the 2nd partition. See for instance [How can I make a 19.04 persistent live USB from Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159851/how-can-i-make-a-19-04-persistent-live-usb-from-windows) or the older [How to make a live Ubuntu 18.04 USB with a persistent storage of more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051543/how-to-make-a-live-ubuntu-18-04-usb-with-a-persistent-storage-of-more-than-4gb)
 and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

You will need a 4Gb stick for Ubuntu 18.04 and newer. 2Gb is too small.

Answer (score 1):

From a CD? Yes (Well, with a DVDR, if you want Ubuntu with a Desktop). A CDR does not have enough space for the complete Ubuntu, not even the smallest complete [flavour](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) ([Lubuntu 19.10](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/)), but all Ubuntus will fit on a DVDR.

The only Ubuntu images which will fit on a CDR are the [Network Installers](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads), which are only suitable to install Ubuntu over the Internet, not to run it, AKA  Core images, such as [Ubuntu Core](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) (Legacy BIOS mode only, not UEFI-capable), [Ubuntu MATE Core](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/), [Xubuntu Core](https://unit193.net/xubuntu/), and [Lubuntu Core](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/updates/lubuntu-core).

You can modify your PC's BIOS/firmware settings to boot from the optical drive if the optical disc is loaded, and if not, to boot from the hard drive.

The same holds true for a USB drive (which will boot much faster, and give you the option of storing files on it) which has been configured as a Ubuntu LiveUSB with [Persistence](https://www.maketecheasier.com/persistent-live-usb-vs-full-install-usb/), and you can do that now with [Ubuntu 19.10](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and the [Rufus windows app](https://rufus.ie) to create the LiveUSB.

USB Flash Drives have gotten very small, less than [half an inch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MPCJDXS) for the part which sticks out of the socket, so it's very convenient to put one of those in a USB socket and carry your laptop around with it loaded.