# installing opera as second browser on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, 22.04, firefox, settings, opera

i just started to use Ubuntu so i am not familiar with this software. please send me link where i can learn if it is possible to leave Firefox as main browser and install opera as second one? i need command lines how to install opera as second browser.

thanks a lot!

best regards,
natasha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Opera Browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291001/how-to-install-opera-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the .deb file of Opera browser from [its website](https://download.opera.com/download/get/?id=62966&location=415&nothanks=yes&sub=marine&utm_tryagain=yes).

Afterwards, double click the .deb file to install it.